# Cannot access internet in ubuntu 18.04. how to fix it?

Tags: network-manager, internet

Suddenly unable to access internet in ubuntu 18.04 despite internet and router working absolutely fine.

ping 8.8.8.8 is fetching data.

Checked ifconfig and Getting the below result

[Ifconfig output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDklL.jpg)

Eth0 is not found in the network interfaces .

Tried reinstalling network manager, restarting service but in vain.

Comment: So eth0 was there before but now it isn't showing? Have you tried bringing it back up?

Comment: Yes tried bringing it up...but says device not found

Comment: From the terminal, if you run ``nmtui`` do you see the interface listed?